# CUDA dot product using blocks of 2D

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I have the following code which works fine when using it with blocks in 1 dimension:

```
__global__ void dot_product_large_arrays( int N, double *a, double *b,
                     double *res)
{

  __shared__ double cache[TILE_DIM];
  int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int i = 0, cacheIndex = 0;
  double temp = 0;
  cacheIndex = threadIdx.x;

  while (tid < N) {
    temp += a[tid] * b[tid];
    tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
  }
  cache[cacheIndex] = temp;
  __syncthreads();

  for (i = blockDim.x/2; i > 0; i>>=1) {
    if (threadIdx.x < i) {
      cache[threadIdx.x] += cache[threadIdx.x + i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  __syncthreads();

  if (cacheIndex == 0) {
    atomicAdd(res, cache[0]);
  }
}
```

Now, my arrays are of size `9000*9000` which don't fit in number of blocks available for the calculation. I've thought to extend it using blocks in `X` and `Y` so my modification is :

```
int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x +
       blockDim.x*gridDim.x*blockIdx.y;
                  ...
while (tid < N) {
    temp += a[tid] * b[tid];
    tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x*blockIdx.y*grimDim.y;
  }
```

and my kernel call

```
int totalThreads = 9000*9000;
int blockSize = 512;
int blockDimY = 256;
int blockDimX = (totalThreads/( blockSize*blockDimY))+ 1;

dim3 dimGrid(blockDimX,blockDimY);
dim3 dimBlock(blockSize);

dot_product_large_arrays <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(totalThreads, d_a, d_b, d_res);
```

It compiles, it runs but never finishes(?!), any ideas of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to run 9000*9000 threads to run this kernel for a 9000*9000 input array. And no need to modify it to use a 2D grid either.

Comment: @talonmies please, could you explain it further? That sounds very interesting

Comment: The while loop with grid stride is intended to be able to accumulate partial sums of an input array *of any length*. That is the whole point of having the loop in the first place.....

Comment: @talonmies I have done what you said. Thanks a lot. It is okay now. However I've noticed that correctness is not good when using 192 threads and `min(8*14,8999*8999)` blocks but it is perfect if using 128 threads and `min(8*14,8999*8999)` blocks. Do you have an explanation for that? It suppose to give peak performance with 192 threads and `min(8*14,8999*8999)` blocks according to the CUDA Occupancy Calculator but for some reason is not giving the right result

Comment: The shared memory reduction requires a power of two number of threads per block. Forgive me for asking, but did you actually write this code, or did you get it from somewhere else? It seems everything you have asked about here stems from a basic lack of understanding of what the code actually does. The NVIDIA examples has an excellent whitepaper by Mark Harris on CUDA implementations of reduction. It seems you might benefit from reading it and studying the code samples it contains.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the line where you are incrementing tid below is the issue:

```
 while (tid < N) {  
    temp += a[tid] * b[tid];  
    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x * blockIdx.y * grimDim.y; //blockIdx.y can be zero
 }
```

At least one of the blocks will have a block y index of 0, which means that you will be incrementing by 0 and causing one or more threads to go into an infinite loop.